# python parse text and add to list

Tags: python, parsing

I have the below output which I am handed via a python function where I receive each line of the below text in a for loop (as info).

```
y.y.y.y:/mount/name mounted on /var/log/da:

 op/s         rpc bklog
2579.20            2.00
read:             ops/s            kB/s           kB/op         retrans         avg RTT (ms)    avg exe (ms)
                1.000           2.000           3.000        4 (4.0%)           5.000           6.000
write:            ops/s            kB/s           kB/op         retrans         avg RTT (ms)    avg exe (ms)
              2578.200        165768.087       64.296        0 (0.0%)          21.394         13980.817

x.x.x.x:/mount/othername mounted on /data:

 op/s         rpc bklog
 5.00            10.00
read:             ops/s            kB/s           kB/op         retrans         avg RTT (ms)    avg exe (ms)
                0.000           0.000           0.000        0 (0.0%)           0.000           0.000
write:            ops/s            kB/s           kB/op         retrans         avg RTT (ms)    avg exe (ms)
                0.000           0.000           0.000        0 (0.0%)           0.000           0.000
```

I ideally would like to have a dictionary that contains the mountname as key followed by a list of all metrics (op/s, rpc, read ops, etc.).

Here is what I have so far:

```
for line in info:
    if ":/" in line[0]:
        section = "mountpoint"
        mountname = line[0]
        continue
    elif "op/s" in line[0]:
        section = "globals"
        continue

    elif "read:" in line[0]:
        section = "reads"
        continue

    elif "write:" in line[0]:
        section = "writes"
        continue

    #if section == "mountpoint":
    #    pass
    if section == "globals":
        mountglobals = line 
        for i in mountglobals:
            infos.append(i)
    if section == "reads":
        reads = line
        for i in reads:
            infos.append(i)
    if section == "writes":
        writes = line
        for i in writes:
            infos.append(i)

    parsed[mountname] = {
        "infos": infos
    }
```

I am missing something in regards to iteration as it will add the keys accordingly but the list of metrics contains all of the metrics. I am not sure how to specify which list of metrics belongs to which mountpoint/key.

Here is what info looks like:

```
[[u'y.y.y.y:/mount/name', u'mounted', u'on', u'/var/log/da:'], [u'op/s', u'rpc', u'bklog'], [u'2579.20', u'2.00'], [u'read:', u'ops/s', u'kB/s', u'kB/op', u'retrans', u'avg', u'RTT', u'(ms)', u'avg', u'exe', u'(ms)'], [u'1.000', u'2.000', u'3.000', u'4', u'(4.0%)', u'5.000', u'6.000'], [u'write:', u'ops/s', u'kB/s', u'kB/op', u'retrans', u'avg', u'RTT', u'(ms)', u'avg', u'exe', u'(ms)'], [u'2578.200', u'165768.087', u'64.296', u'0', u'(0.0%)', u'21.394', u'13980.817'], [u'x.x.x.x:/mount/othername', u'mounted', u'on', u'/data:'], [u'op/s', u'rpc', u'bklog'], [u'5.00', u'10.00'], [u'read:', u'ops/s', u'kB/s', u'kB/op', u'retrans', u'avg', u'RTT', u'(ms)', u'avg', u'exe', u'(ms)'], [u'0.000', u'0.000', u'0.000', u'0', u'(0.0%)', u'0.000', u'0.000'], [u'write:', u'ops/s', u'kB/s', u'kB/op', u'retrans', u'avg', u'RTT', u'(ms)', u'avg', u'exe', u'(ms)'], [u'0.000', u'0.000', u'0.000', u'0', u'(0.0%)', u'0.000', u'0.000']]
```

Here is what my current output looks like:

```
{u'y.y.y.y:/mount/name': {'infos': [u'2579.20', u'2.00', u'1.000', u'2.000', u'3.000', u'4', u'(4.0%)', u'5.000', u'6.000', u'2578.200', u'165768.087', u'64.296', u'0', u'(0.0%)', u'21.394', u'13980.817', u'5.00', u'10.00', u'0.000', u'0.000', u'0.000', u'0', u'(0.0%)', u'0.000', u'0.000', u'0.000', u'0.000', u'0.000', u'0', u'(0.0%)', u'0.000', u'0.000']}, u'x.x.x.x:/mount/othername': {'infos': [u'2579.20', u'2.00', u'1.000', u'2.000', u'3.000', u'4', u'(4.0%)', u'5.000', u'6.000', u'2578.200', u'165768.087', u'64.296', u'0', u'(0.0%)', u'21.394', u'13980.817', u'5.00', u'10.00', u'0.000', u'0.000', u'0.000', u'0', u'(0.0%)', u'0.000', u'0.000', u'0.000', u'0.000', u'0.000', u'0', u'(0.0%)', u'0.000', u'0.000']}}
```

Appreciate some hints.

Comment: you should format your input/output text like code, otherwise this is hard to read, So put four spaces at the beginning of each line.

Comment: thank you, it seems blhsing already formatted the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless your input is extremely large, which I don't think is the case, I would recommend that you read the entire input into one string (the following example assumes that have all your input in the variable `s`), and use `re.findall` to more easily parse the mount names and the associated 16 numbers for each mount name:

```
import re
parsed = {m[0]: m[1:] for m in re.findall(r'(\S+:/\S+)%s' % (r'.*?([\d.]+)' * 16), s, flags=re.DOTALL)}
```

`parsed` would become:

```
{'y.y.y.y:/mount/name': ('2579.20', '2.00', '1.000', '2.000', '3.000', '4', '4.0', '5.000', '6.000', '2578.200', '165768.087', '64.296', '0', '0.0', '21.394', '13980.817'), 'x.x.x.x:/mount/othername': ('5.00', '10.00', '0.000', '0.000', '0.000', '0', '0.0', '0.000', '0.000', '0.000', '0.000', '0.000', '0', '0.0', '0.000', '0.000')}
```

Comment: Thank you. It does not work for me, probably because I did not provide you with the format of the info list which does not contain empty lines.

Comment: My solution should ignore blank lines and newlines since it simply looks for mount names (that contain `':/'`) and floating numbers, regardless of what's in between. Can you show me how you read the entire input into one string, in order to apply my solution?

Comment: Im using s = ','.join(str(v) for v in info). I may have made a typo when I tested earlier, I will try again shortly as I think it should work

Comment: The dictionary is there but is in a strange format. I am not sure how to clean it up. For example: for k, v in parsed.iteritems(): print (k) gives me [u'y.y.y.y:/mount/name',
'],[u'x.x.x.x:/mount/othername',

Comment: It does indeed work. My conversion to a single string was not correct.